# Angular Cannot find module './dropdown-basic'.ts(2307)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, dropdown

I tried to add a Bootstrap DropDown to my angular project. when I tried to import Bootstrap DropDown to app.module.ts file; by adding following code line,

```
import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic';
```

I am getting below error.

> Cannot find module './dropdown-basic'.ts(2307)

I tried to resolve this issue by remove node_modules and re-installed them, but issue is still there. Please check package.json. Can I manually install that package by any chance?

package.json

```
{
    "name": "lbd-free-angular-cli",
    "version": "1.6.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start"
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/common": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/compiler": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/core": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/forms": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/localize": "^9.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/router": "9.0.6",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^6.0.2",
        "@ngui/map": "0.30.3",
        "@types/googlemaps": "3.39.3",
        "animate.css": "3.7.0",
        "arrive": "2.4.1",
        "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
        "bootstrap-notify": "3.1.3",
        "chartist": "0.11.0",
        "core-js": "2.6.9",
        "googleapis": "33.0.0",
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "perfect-scrollbar": "1.4.0",
        "rxjs": "6.5.4",
        "rxjs-compat": "6.5.4",
        "zone.js": "0.10.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.900.6",
        "@angular/cli": "9.0.6",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "9.0.6",
        "@types/jasmine": "3.5.9",
        "@types/node": "13.9.0",
        "codelyzer": "5.2.1",
        "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
        "karma": "4.4.1",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
        "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
        "karma-jasmine": "3.1.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.2",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
        "protractor": "5.4.3",
        "ts-node": "8.6.2",
        "tslint": "6.1.0",
        "typescript": "3.7.5"
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { NavbarModule } from './shared/navbar/navbar.module';
import { FooterModule } from './shared/footer/footer.module';
import { SidebarModule } from './sidebar/sidebar.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './layouts/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NavbarModule,
    FooterModule,
    SidebarModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminLayoutComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

output

[image]

Comment: in app.module you imports and include in `imports` "Modules" , NOT component, you import a component and include in `declarations` "Components" if you want to use (your NgbdDropdownBasic is a component), read carefully the docs: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

import { NgbdDropdownBasic } from './dropdown-basic';

This is a wrong import, I think that your are following the Documentation and you think that this is some important import for the dropdown but it's not.

If you already have imported this in your module:

import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

Then you are good to go. Check this how I have used the dropdown module:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngbd-dropdown-module

Comment: you answer was very useful and I updated my answer by adding a screen shot of the result.. can you please check and explain a bit about what should I do to make it pretty ?

Comment: Have you imported Bootstrap's Css?

Comment: The stackblitz link I shared. Try to check the css in index.html file

Comment: Or you can share your repo with me and I can see the issue. So far it's seem like a css issue

Comment: okay I'll create a github repo and will get back to you. Thank you so much for helping @Immad

Comment: any time not an issue

Comment: here's the link to my  Github Repo. would you kind enough to add required css files to me? https://github.com/MrMalith/IPT_Application I'm new to Angular and btw this is a template also. I tried to add a drop down to end of UserProfile. and thank you!

Comment: I will check it now and will get back to you.

Comment: Thank you @Immad you are free to add issues in the Github repo

Comment: The issue that I have found is that you have imported the NgbModule in wrong place, you should have imported it in admin-layout.module but still this would not work as you wish because you are already using a dashboard theme which already provide this all stuff. On top of it uses the bootstrap lib and overwrites it completely. It uses poper.js and solutions like ng-bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap are something that try to remove poper.js usage. So there are conflicts. In your case only the import was wrong. If you try to the same in new project then it will work. Do you still wish to use or what?

Comment: I will create another project then, it would be great right? otherwise this template would be a mess. Again thank you so much for helping. I really appreciate that @Immad